# implement additional function to event - Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How can I add an additional function to take place when an item is expanded? Below I've attempted to re-implement the expandItem event but it doesn't appear to do anything. Why is that?

```
# QTreeWidgets
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class FactionsTreeWidget( QtGui.QTreeWidget ):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setItemsExpandable(True)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

    def itemExpanded( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        res = super( self, my_class ).itemExpanded( *args, **kwargs )
        print "expanding stuff..."
        return res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itemExpanded` is a signal emitted by `QTreeWidget`, not one of it's method.
So you just need to connect this signal to your function.

```
    ...
    self.itemExpanded.connect(self.onItemExpanded)

def onItemExpanded(self,item):
    print("stuff")
```

Comment: thank you. im not super familiar with this language so i appreciate the help and explanation.